# How to limit number of objects in spring prototype scope

Tags: java, spring

I have a pojo which contains a result set. If I allow all the threads to create their own object, the system runs out of memory very quickly. In the same time, I don't want to use Singleton as it keeps the thread waiting and slows down the processing. Is there any way I can limit the number of object to let say to 20. We are using spring. Any help would be greatly appreciated. cheers.

Comment: why dont you keep limit on no of thread in threadpool

Comment: No, its not possible, all the threads should run... At the moment I use singleton, it works fine but want to improve the performance.

Comment: Don't keep state in your singleton that way multiple threads can use the same object.

Comment: Its like a JDBC resultset object, I do some processing on result. so the next thread has to wait.

Comment: Is the result set modified during the execution?

Comment: No but its being read. So it will be locked until all the records are processed.

Comment: Any Ideas for this please?